# MTLocation how-to

Tags: ios, object, mapkit, core-location

Hi I just came across MTLocation here: https://github.com/darkseed/MTLocation.

I want to use a locate me button in my app which will be located in navigation bar and when pressed will move the map to current location.

The author proposes to use the code like this:

```
// Configure Location Manager
[MTLocationManager sharedInstance].locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[MTLocationManager sharedInstance].locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
[MTLocationManager sharedInstance].locationManager.headingFilter = 5; // 5 Degrees

// create locate-me item
MTLocateMeBarButtonItem *locateMeItem = [[[MTLocateMeBarButtonItem alloc] initWithLocationStatus:MTLocationStatusIdle] autorelease];
// set delegate that is called when mode of Button changes
locateMeItem.delegate = [MTLocationManager sharedInstance];
// add target-action
[locateMeItem addTarget:self action:@selector(myCustomSelector:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
// disable heading
locateMeItem.headingEnabled = NO;

// create array with ToolbarItems
NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:locateMeItem];
// set toolbar items
[self.toolbar setItems:toolbarItems animated:NO];
```

which is great to show a locate me button in toolbar but how can we make this work to show current location through gps? I guess tha we have to implement myCustomSelector method but I do not know how. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

And then implement myCustomSelector:, for example like this:

```
- (void) myCustomSelector:(MTLocateMeBarButtonItem*) button {
    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate];
}
```

You'll need to take care of a proper functionality at different button modes (whether MTLocateMeBarButton is Idle, or something else), but that should give you a direction.